# Managing instances with Autoscaling groups - cannot detatch an instance that is in standby

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling

I get the following error when I try to detach an instance in standby from my asg:

> Trying to detach instance(s) resulted in failure AutoScalingGroup
> .io has min-size=1, max-size=1, and desired-size=1. To detach 1
> instance, please update the AutoScalingGroup sizes appropriately.

This is what the instances look like

[image: asg instances showing one is in stand by and one is in service]

And these are my ASG sizes:

[image: asg size config showing 1 for desired, min, and max instances]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised I needed to set it back to in-service to detach it. Looks like setting an instance to out of service is similar to detaching the instance.